# elements show in code source but element.length returns as Zero

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a list of dynamically generated h3's, but when I run queryselectorall on the classname it returns as zero, even though there are 4 elements showing in the source code.
I've read about the DOM not loading but all attempts to fix this have not worked.

I have tried to shorten the code, but it uses localstorage to keep elements over sessions. You will notice that when using hardcoded h3's the change textcontent works, but with the dynamic h3's it doesn't.

Please advise. I appreciate the help.

```js
const projectForm = document.querySelector("#project-form");
const projectList = [];
projectForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const project = {
    name: e.target.elements.projectName.value
  }
  projectList.push(project);
  e.target.reset();
  addProject();

})

function addProject() {
  const listOfProjects = document.querySelector("#projects-list");
  listOfProjects.innerHTML = "";

  projectList.forEach(project => {
    let newProjectName = document.querySelector("#project-name").value;
    const newProject = document.createElement("h2");
    newProject.classList.add("project");
    newProject.textContent = "- " + project.name;

    listOfProjects.appendChild(newProject);
  })
};

let projectTitle = document.querySelectorAll(".project");
const selectedProject = document.querySelector("#task-title .task-title");
// selectedProject.textContent = projectTitle.length;

for (let pt = 0; pt < projectTitle.length; pt++) {
  projectTitle[pt].addEventListener("click", function() {
    let pTitle = projectTitle[pt].textContent;
    selectedProject.textContent = pTitle;
  });
}
```

```html
<h2 id="task-title">Add new task to <span class="task-title">Default project</span>.

  <h3>Projects</h3>
  <div id="projects-list">
    <!--<h2 class="project">One</h2>
<h2 class="project">Two</h2>-->
  </div>
  <div id="add-project-box">
    <form id="project-form">
      <input type="text" id="project-name" name="projectName" placeholder="New Project Name">
      <input type="submit" id="add-project-button" value="Add Project">
    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: _`let projectTitle = document.querySelectorAll(".project")`_  this runs before you've added any matching elements. Use event delegation to listen for events on dynamically added elements. See the duplicate for jQuery and vanilla JS examples